# Checking for result when using < sqlite3

Tags: command-line, sqlite

I need to know if this command is either successful or failure, inside a script .sh file.

```
sqlite3 database.db < database.sql
```

I'm thinking something like:

```
$result = ('sqlite3 database.db < database.sql')
```

where if the $result contains something, I bail. Else if the result does not contain anything, I continue on.

Comment: So here is what is happening now...
I run this in my script: 
sqlite3 database.db < database.sql

I see this output: Error: near line 1: near "ï»¿": syntax error

Would there be a way to check for the "Error" or "error"

Answer (score 0):

The `sqlite3` tool will return the normal error status, which you can check with the normal shell methods (`if`, `$?`, etc.):

```sh
$ if sqlite3 test.db "select 42;"; then echo success; else echo failure; fi
42
success
$ if sqlite3 test.db "select x;"; then echo success; else echo failure; fi
Error: no such column: x
failure
```